# Algorithm to find the most frequent words

Tags: python, algorithm, datetime, time-complexity

I can't think of an algorithm for my code. Please help me out.

We have two files. The first one has text (Text length is n-words). The second one contains "word synonyms". That is, in one row will be written the initial form of the word, after its forms. For example

- **house**, **hours*, *how*, *housing**

The length of this file is m words.
The files are very long.

I need to find the 100 most frequent words in the first file. If we find the word **computer** and *complete* and *comfy*, it will be counted as one word (because they are in the same row in the second file) **computer** (initial form). But the counter of this word is already equal to three.

Help to find the fastest algorithm for the solution. And what time complexity will be based on n, m.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

- Parse the synonyms file into a `dict` that maps the synonyms to their main word.
- Replace every word by its main synonym, if it has one, or keep it if it doesn't. If `syn_dict` is the dict of synonyms and `word` is a word, then `syn_dict.get(word, word)` will return `word`'s main synonym if it's in the dict, or return `word` otherwise.
- Use `collections.Counter` to count all the words.
- Use method `.most_common` of `Counter` to extract the 100 most frequent words.

Emulating the text files with `StringIO` for reproducibility:

```py
from io import StringIO
from collections import Counter

textfile = StringIO('''The house is comfy and complete with computers
It has been housing a computer for hours''')
synonymfile = StringIO('''computer, comfy, complete, computers
house, hours, how, housing''')

syn_dict = {}
for line in synonymfile:
    word, *synonyms = map(str.strip, line.split(','))
    for s in synonyms:
        syn_dict[s] = word

print(syn_dict)
# {'comfy': 'computer', 'complete': 'computer', 'computers': 'computer',
#  'hours': 'house', 'how': 'house', 'housing': 'house'}

c = Counter(syn_dict.get(word, word) for line in textfile for word in line.lower().split())

print( c.most_common(100) )
# [('computer', 4), ('house', 3), ('the', 1), ('is', 1),
#  ('and', 1), ('with', 1), ('it', 1), ('has', 1),
#  ('been', 1), ('a', 1), ('for', 1)]
```

With actual files it should look like this:

```py
from collections import Counter

with open('file2.txt', 'r') as synonymfile:
    syn_dict = {}
    for line in synonymfile:
        word, *synonyms = map(str.strip, line.split(','))
        for s in synonyms:
            syn_dict[s] = word

with open('file1.txt', 'r') as textfile:
    c = Counter(syn_dict.get(word, word) for line in textfile for word in line.lower().split())

print( c.most_common(100) )
# [('computer', 4), ('house', 3), ('the', 1), ('is', 1),
#  ('and', 1), ('with', 1), ('it', 1), ('has', 1),
#  ('been', 1), ('a', 1), ('for', 1)]
```

Comment: Thank you, as I understand the hourly complexity will be  O(N+N). But there is this question. What if syn_dict  takes up more memory than necessary?  It's just that my files are such that they won't go all the way to the computer's internal memory.

Comment: @Katli Are the synonyms actual real English words? There aren't enough English words in the dictionary that this would be an issue.

Comment: Yes, English, but it could still happen that there is not enough computer memory.

Comment: @Katli I've loaded all of the Scrabble official dictionary in a python `dict` and never ran into any memory issues.

Comment: ok, thank you very much, I understand the algorithm.)